# python, lxml and how to get html code from subset

Tags: python, html, lxml

I use this function to get this section of the html doc.

```
for el in doc.find_class('plusShippingText'):
      print el
```

What I need is the html code.  How can I print the html code for el?

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`lxml.html.tostring`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.html-module.html#tostring)

```
print lxml.html.tostring(el)
```